# how to check the size of input to avoid exceed DB column limit

Tags: oracle, jsp, encoding

I have an input field of my page with size=8.

And in the DB, the corresponding column is VARCHAR2(8).

But if I input a string of length 8 with a special ascii character in the field, I will get the following exception.

ORA-12899: value too large for column xxxx (actual: 10, maximum: 8)

I'm trying to catch this in the validator, I check myString.getBytes().length which is also 8.

I know one solution is on DB side that change the column to VARCHAR2(8 CHAR).

Is there another solution that I can check this in the controller?

Comment: "special ascii character" doesn't make sense - you mean a multibyte/unicode character, or at least a non-ASCII character, right? ASCII characters are always single-byte.

Comment: Yes. I mean multibyte/unicode character. 

Actually, I input a Chinese character.

Comment: I believe the byte length of characters is (at least sometimes) dependent on the character set. So it is not possible to do this check without knowing at least **something** from the DB, namely the DB character set. I am not sure what `myString.getBytes().length` is supposed to return - how can it know, without taking a character set as an argument? It will then be in some default character set (perhaps the OS character set?)

Comment: @mathguy - it is [the platform's default charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()). It can optionally take a charset argument, but don't think that's helpful here. I don't think the DB character set should relevant to the Java/JSP check if the column is defined as 8 bytes, which the question implies (as *changing* to 8 char is an option)? But, if `getBytes().length()` is reporting 8 anyway, seems like there could be some unintended conversion between Java/JSP and the DB, possibly due to a character set mismatch?

Comment: @AlexPoole - that's what I meant. I don't know what "platform" means, but there is no reason why the platform character set should match the DB character set. If the same character is one byte in the platform character set but 3 bytes in the DB, that may explain the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that you've given 10 bytes but the column only allows 8. I am assuming it's bytes because of your use of the Chinese character set. So, I believe that the column was created as if it were VARCHAR2(8 byte).

If you describe the table, you'll see what's going on. Compare that describe with a describe of this one:

```
create table x (a varchar2(30), b varchar2(30 byte), c varchar2(30 char));
```

The code you are executing to obtain the number of bytes is almost correct. Instead of:

```
myString.getBytes().length   /* this probably returns 8 */
```

you need to execute this:

```
myString.getBytes("UTF-8").length /* this probably returns 10 */
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you, this will return the actual size in Bytes.

```
SELECT LENGTHB ('é') 
   FROM DUAL;
```

Above will return 2. So whatever character you are using, you can specify something like `MY_VARCHAR_FIELD VARCHAR2(2 BYTES)`

Comment: Isn't the OP trying to catch this *before* going to the database?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without calling DB?

Comment: @DavidRuan Yes, please look at my answer.